# React Component does not re rendering when updating an object in state hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-component

Why this component does not update when the state updating? But, when the file is updated (like editing and saving the code), the component will re-rendering and show the correct value from the updated state. Here is the code

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const init = [
  {
    name: "Car",
    stock: 100
  },
  {
    name: "Truck",
    stock: 50
  }
];

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "add") { 
    state[0].stock++;
    return state;
  } else { 
    return state;
  }
};


export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, init);
  const addCarStock = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "add" });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Car Stock : {state[0].stock}</p>
      <button onClick={addCarStock}>Add Car Stock</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can open this code in [sandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-mcnulty-7ygxr?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `state[0].stock++;`. It changes the existing array(you can actually check that array updated by putting a `console.log(state);` in the first line of reducer function) and when react does rendering it does a shallow comparison (reference checking) and ignores re-render assuming it is the same array (because prev and new state refer to the same instance).

You need to create a new array instance (`state`) with the changes and return it.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "add") {
    return state.map((item,itemIndex) => {
      if(itemIndex === 0){
        return {...item, stock: item.stock + 1}
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
  } else {
    return state;
  }
};
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-davinci-iid5h?file=/src/App.js